# Redis data architecture for user login check

Tags: redis, nosql

I first time at Redis. I want to create most flexible architecture for my project (with cluster in future or now).
My primary datastore - Redis and now, i rewriting repositories:
I have EntityFramework repository:

```
public class UserRepository : CommonRepository<User, Guid>
{
    public async Task<bool> IsLoginExists(string email)
    {
        return await ExistsAsync(user => user.Email == email);
    }

    public async Task<bool> CheckLoginPassword(string email, string password)
    {
        return await ExistsAsync(user => user.Email == email && user.Password == password);
    }

    public User GetByEmail(string email)
    {
        return FindOne(user => user.Email == email);
    }
}
```

All users persists as **{user:ab1a8d80-1fdb-4668-b477-f92be4815e1c}** and hashEntry for all other properties.
But i have no expirience and i want to store user logins (i don't want to join it in key).
What the best practice ? For sharding and simply queries...
Crate key UserLogins and add Hash with all userLogins ? It's not possible to query this information.

**Create key: {user_login:test@mail.com} value: ab1a8d80-1fdb-4668-b477-f92be4815e1c** ?

Answer (score 0):

From Redis book i get answer!

```
set users:9001 "{id: 9001, email: leto@dune.gov, ...}"
hset users:lookup:email leto@dune.gov 9001
```